# Using awt.Robot with Tomcat service

Tags: java, tomcat, service, awtrobot

I am trying to simulate user input (keyboard) using Robot library from java.awt, and it is working on my development enviroment, but when deploying to Tomcat (installed as a service on a different machine), it wont work at all. My OS is Windows.

Is there any configuration that I am missing? I already tried "let tomcat interact with the desktop" option, changing users to run the service, changing java used by tomcat (from jre/ to jdk/jre/..), but still I can't make it work.

Also, if it is not possible, is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you sure that processes running as a *service* in windows machine can get access to the desktop at all? Doesn't matter if it's tomcat or any other service.

Comment: No I am not sure, how can I check this? Right now I just checked an option in "Services - Tomcat" and then tab "logon" and option "Allow service to interact with desktop" using local system account (but the application which I want to interact is opened in another user session), so I changed the user used in logon by the service and used the same but didn't work either.

Comment: Ok, I realized tomcat is running as session 0, and after lots of triel I'm able to see a message prompt of "Interactive Services Detection", if I see the message I'm redirected to session 0 in which the robot tries to emulate keyboard input but just after I see it graphically. So, is there a way to "Automatically open session 0 when ISD is prompted??

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this, not in the best way I guess.

I stopped Tomcat Service, and then started it from CMD as the current user.

Steps to open tomcat from cmd:

1. Open cmd.exe
2. Path-to-tomcat\bib\tomcat7.exe

And then opened my browser, went to the application, tried the proccess and the robot worked correctly!

I know this is not the best way as it can led to security issues, but I couldn't make it work using it as a Service because the different user sessiones (Session 0).